# Javascript promises run sequentially

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I've been playing around with promises and javascript, specifically bluebird.js.

From reading the docs, it appears if you want to chain promises you can use `Promise.all([p1, p2, p3])` and return the values as an array... `[1,2,3]`.  Or `Promise.props()` to return an object reference.

How would I construct a method where each promise returns a value that gets passed to the next promise, mutating the value where required?  If anyone can give an example would be great.

Answer:

```
function Test(value) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        resolve(value);
    }, 500);
  }).then(function(value){
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(function(){
          value += ", nice hat!";
          resolve(value);
        }, 2000);  
    });
  }).then(function(value){
    console.log(value);
  });
}

var test = new Test("Hi Promise");
```

Comment: Do you really need promises for what you describe? `f3(f2(f1()));`

Comment: @blgt: how would that work if every function does something asynchronous?

Comment: @FelixKling It wouldn't.

Comment: I've got some code that returns a promise.  Otherwise it could be achieved using callbacks. I worked it out... needed to return a nested promise. See fiddle for code. http://jsfiddle.net/kwj8kg98/

Comment: I edited the above to show answer....